# How to edit a cell in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am working in .NET 2.0 with C# and database is SQL SERVER 2005. I am using DataGridView. I had enabled "Enable Editing" Checkbox. Eventhough, I am not able to edit any cell.Please, give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the properties of the DataGridView and make sure that the `EditMode` is set to the correct value (According to what you need), that `ReadOnly` is false, that `Enabled` is true.

Comment: Every thing I had done what you told, but also I can't able to edit.

Comment: Did you check Adam's suggestion about columns? Also, what is the `EditMode` set to? And how are you trying to edit the DGV?

Comment: Yes, I cheked. Everything is correctly given as You and Adam suggested. Now, I am searching for some programmatic edits. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I deleted old DGV and add a new DGV. Now, I can able to edit, delete. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Also, individual columns can have a readonly flag, check that too.